# Embed Power BI content into an application for your organization users - Need Admin Approval Error

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are trying to embed PowerBI report in the website and we have followed the step from below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization

We have download the User Owns Data sample from GitHub to get started. Now, We are getting below error while running the application.

https://oxcrx34285.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/181463i44C126096E9419F3/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

SAT Report 5 app created on Azure --> App Registration and It's having following permissions.

https://oxcrx34285.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/181462i5D003092A86DE647/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

As we got an error of need admin approval, Do we need to set up the app using Admin login?

Answer (score 0):

On portal.azure.com, got to App Registrations and select your application. Under Manage click the API Permissions link. On the bottom of this page there is a Grant Admin Consent button. If you dont see the button you dont have permission and will have to connect with whoever manages your tenant.

[image: API Permissions]

Comment: [@vvvv4d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2344394/vvvv4d) is right. Besides, admin approval prompt also appears when you try to login using an account from a different tenant.